# how to get sum(group) value in rdlc

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I am developing report in RDLC (VS 2012)

below is my report
In this report i have two group total value matrix table.
I want to minus Sum(income) and sum(expenses).
Total should be show as 2121.00
how its possible ?
[image: Report Output]

[image: Report in Design mode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!VoucherType.Value = "Income",Fields!Amount.Value,0))-
SUM(IIF(Fields!VoucherType.Value = "Expenses",Fields!Amount.Value,0))
```

### Update

Textbox outside of the tablix.

If you want to show the total outside of the tablix you need to set the scope of the expression, in this case the dataset:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!VoucherType.Value = "Income",Fields!Amount.Value,0),"DataSetName")-
SUM(IIF(Fields!VoucherType.Value = "Expenses",Fields!Amount.Value,0),"DataSetName")
```

Replace `DataSetName` by the actual name of your dataset.

Comment: getting the same result of sum(Amount). Not working out side of Tablix

Comment: @padh, try the updated expression if you want to show it outside the tablix.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!TransactionType.Value = 1), Fields!Amount.Value, 0) -
SUM(IIF(Fields!TransactionType.Value = 2), Fields!Amount.Value, 0)
```